# How to manage many queries on 1 page?

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way to manage more than 1 query on a page. I am using 4 different queries on one page all of which are just using the variable $query in sequence, so like each query on the page is situated in different areas and as the page loads from top to bottom each query is completed.

I have placed each query in a separate file and included it in the area where i am echoing the data. Is this bad? Should i place them all in one file and use a separate variable for each queries eg $result 1, $row1 then for second query $result 2, $row2 so on so fourth.

Thanks

Comment: If you feel that you can overlap any query, just add another "query" variable and that's all. You can add as many queries as memory you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i don't think it's a good idea to use always the same variable for a query, especially for results that should have meaningful names like $numberOfMessages, $countUsers ... remember that the most important thing is that your code is readable by others who might have to mantain it. Spend a little time to write meaningful name for variables.

Speaking of queries, i think it's not a problem to have 4 queries on one page, just make sure that the queries just retrieve the data you want...spend some time optimizing the queries because fetching a lot of data from mysql is a performance killer.

EDIT

for example i use:

```
//import the db configuration
require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . 'libs/confDbSugarcrm.php');
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
//list your queries (i use joomla classes in this example)

$sqlUsers = "select id, name from table_users";
$db->setQuery($sqlUsers); 
$usersIdName = $db->loadObjectList();


$sqlNumberOfMessages = "select count(id) as how_many from table_messages";
$db->setQuery($sqlNumberOfMessages); 
$numberOfMessages = $db->loadResult();
```

And so on...this way you code is readable, you avoid clashing variabales name...you life is easier i think (and using different and meaningful names for variables is a best practice).

Comment: if i were to give them all meaningful variables should i then, include them all in 1 file which is then included at the top of the page or should i leave them on the actual page or in separate files?

Comment: I usually leave them inline and grouped so that it's clear What sql is linked to what result...usually i leave configuration file outside so that you have them only in one place. I've edited my answer to show an example

Comment: Of course if you use an MVC pattern (look here for what it means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) you would have all the sql and queries in the model part, my example it's just form simpler piece of code

Answer (score 1):

Forums, online cart programs and the such will often have 10 or 20+ queries per page. 4 is not ganna kill you straight up.

Comment: ok, good to know but should i just leave them on the actual page or in separate pages which are included or the third option, putting them all in 1 file?

Comment: I find no issue with leaving them inline. If you find it is making your code look messy you could possibly create a file with multiple functions for each query that you give parameters and it returns the customised query based on the parameters of the function.